# Выбрать элементы по классу и собрать значения атрибутов

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, yii2

Делаю [**поиск картинок по тегам**](https://dota.gallery/site/search) на сайте-галерее. C [**самим поиском**](https://dota.gallery/site/search?tags=24-12-5) и выводом его результатов разобрался, а сама инициализация поиска мне не поддаётся, а именно: вот на странице три ряда блоков, каждый из которых представляет из себя тег, каждый блок при клике получает/теряет класс tagActive, каждый блок имеет атрибут tag-id, который содержит в себе id соответствующего тега. 
**Что нужно?** Нужно как-то при клике на кнопку собрать значения атрибутов tag-id у блоков, которые имеют класс tagActive (то есть у выбранных тегов) и в идиале поместить их в php массив для использования в $_GET. Я понимаю, что начать нужно как-то так:

```
$(function(){
     $('.btn').click(function(){
        var actives = $('.tagActive').attr("tag-id");
    });
});
```

но довести этот код до конца у меня никак не получается =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее наоборот. Поместить в GET-массив для использования в PHP

```
$(function(){
     $('.btn').click(function(){
        var actives = new Array();
        $('.tagActive').each(function(){
            actives.push($(this).attr("tag-id"));
        });
        var to_url = 'http://www/leningrad.spb.ru?';
        for(i =0; i <actives.length; i++){
            to_url += 'id[]=' + actives[i] + '&';
        }
        $('<form>').attr('method', 'get').attr('action', to_url).appendTo('body').submit();

    });
});
```

Comment: Спсибо больше, однако я не смог воспользоваться вашим ответом в полной мере, а в частности последней строчкой. Вместо него я просто генерировал нужную ссылку в переменной to_url, пользовался методом  document.location.href и там уже полученные GET данные подхватывались PHP и работа пошла. Однако хотелось бы узнать значение последней строчки, я понял лишь это: выбрать_форму.установить_метод_гет.не_знаю.добавить_в_боди.отправить_форму

Comment: Не выбрать форму, а создать, настроить, добавить на страницу и сразу отправить.

Comment: О location.href не подумал. Действительно, в данном случае он намного лучше.